# Excel: search for multiple terms in a cell and give me position of the first positive result

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to search through a list of values in excel and wrap the first part of the text with quotes. The only way to know where the end of the first part is, is to search for one of many words. For example

If my string was "Account THR Exp Date char NULL," 
and my list of trigger words is {"nvarchar","varchar","int","char","TIMESTAMP"}
then I need the search function to return 21 to me.

What is the formula for this in Excel?

Comment: VBA would be easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider:

```
Public Function FindStuff(MyString As String) As Long
    ary = Array("nvarchar", "varchar", "int", "char", "TIMESTAMP")
    For Each a In ary
        If InStr(MyString, a) > 0 Then FindStuff = InStr(MyString, a)
    Next a
End Function
```

So:

[image]